# Attributes of a Session from JSP to Servlet returning null

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

In the beginning of my JSP file, I have this code:

```
<%@page language="java" session="true" %>
<%session.setAttribute("foo", "bar"); %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">
<head>
...
```

In this JSP file, some data is sent to a Servlet through `POST`. I can retrieve that data, however, if I do this:

```
 if (session.getAttribute("foo").equals("bar")){
      do something
  }
```

I get a `NullPointerException`. Why doesn't `foo` exists on my servlet?

Comment: check whether session null?

Comment: How do you get your session object in servlet?

Comment: ok, but why the attribute `foo` doesn't exist, if I created it on JSP?

Comment: @px5x2 `HttpSession session = request.getSession();`

Comment: Well, i'd track `setAttribute` and `getAttribute` implementations of underlying session manager by debugging.

Comment: In any case what you're doing is bad practice. You should assume that sometimes session attributes will be null. The session could expire. Someone could hit this page before hitting the other. So don't write `if (session.getAttribute("foo").equals("bar"))` but rather something like `if ("bar".equals(session.getAttribute("foo")))` which will not throw a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this way it works.

JSP

```
<%session.setAttribute("foo", "bar");%>
<form action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/TestServlet" method="POST">
 <input type="submit" value="Post"  />
</form>
```

TestServlet

```
if (request.getSession().getAttribute("foo").equals("bar")){
  System.out.println("Success");
}
```